# Apache error_log: File does not exist - undefinedadapters

Tags: php, apache, error-log

Browsing through the error_log, it seems to be flooded with the following error:

```
[Mon Feb 15] [error] [client {ip}] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/{site}/httpdocs/undefinedadapters, referer: {page-1.php}

[Mon Feb 15] [error] [client {ip}] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/{site}/httpdocs/undefinedadapters, referer: {page-2.php}
```

Done a few google searches, but I can't seem to find anything relevant.
Any ideas for what/where to look at ?

Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Oct 16 2014 14:48:21
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:25
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit

PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Oct 30 2014 20:12:53)
Zend Engine v2.3.0,
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.6.0

Should I post the httpd.conf as well ? Having trouble formatting it here.

Thank you.